# How can I add my own parameters in logback pattern configuration?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have some logback configuration:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

How can I add my own parameters in pattern?
Something like:

```
<pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} %user.name %status - %msg%n</pattern>
```

Comment: Plz accepte my answer if it helped you. It could help others also

Answer (score 10):

Consider use of Logback Mapped Diagnostic Contexts [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) then put the parameter in MDC like this `MDC.put( "userName", "George" );`.
To print it with patternLayout do `<pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} %X{userName} %status - %msg%n</pattern>`